# database delivery option for subscribed ssrs reports

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a reports which is taking 20 minutes to run .I want to make it as subscribed ssrs report.I have seen that in SSRS the delivery options are email and fileshare but I want the report to be saved in DB directly.Is there a way of inserting the report in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a snapshot based on parameters to be rendered. If your report follows a model that allows it to be subscribed to with parameters similar to the snapshot then you can create a batch type process. This works if your users are not expecting real-time data.

For example:

1. Early in the morning create a snapshot.
2. Email cached version based on similar parameters.

Hope this helps.